# Populate fields after redirect in struts 2

Tags: forms, validation, redirect, parameters, struts2

I'm trying to understand if there is an easiest and shorter way to populate the fields of a form, after it fails validation and it's redirected (following the pattern described [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post)).

I have a form that is called from addPerson.action action, and submit action is savePerson.action.
If it fails validation, I redirect passing all parameters, so that the redirected page will populate the fields with the data inserted by the user, avoiding the user the hassle to start from scratch.
The problem of this solution is that I have to list every single parameter of the form in the struts.xml, like in the example below:

```
<action name="savePerson" class="personAction" method="savePerson">
        <interceptor-ref name="store">
            <param name="operationMode">STORE</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="myStack" />
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">listPeople</param>
        </result>
        <result name="input" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">addPerson</param>
            <param name="parse">true</param>
            <param name="person.name">${person.name}</param>
            <param name="person.surname">${person.surname}</param>
            <param name="person.gender">${person.gender}</param>
            <param name="person.email">${person.email}</param>
            <param name="person.mobile">${person.mobile}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
    <action name="addPerson" class="personAction" method="addPerson">
        <interceptor-ref name="store">
            <param name="operationMode">RETRIEVE</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="myStack" />
        <result name="success">/person/add.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/person/add.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

I had to use the MessageStoreInterceptor in order to save and retrieve the validation error messages from a redirect.

I'm already using the ajax validation, but I wish to make my pages work in non javascript mode as well. With the code above everything works as expected, but looks weird that I have to list all my parameters inside the result tag.

Is there a better and shorter way of doing it?
thanks

Comment: Just curious... what is it that you are doing in `addPerson` method that you need to redirect to it when validation fails?  Because typically, I would have `<result name="input">/person/add.jsp</result>` as a result of `savePerson` action and that would have sufficed.

Comment: But if you hit refresh after validation fails, the browser asks if you want to resubmit the form, which is one of the issues described [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post)

Comment: nmc is correct. Don't redirect after validation failures. The redirect-after-post pattern is intended for the follow up page, not for redisplaying the input page to correct validation errors. Redirect once validation is successful and you have processed your form.

Comment: What if the input page needs to prepopulate data? In that case do I need to redirect to the action (that populates the data) instead of the jsp?

Answer (score 0):

With a redirect you start over, you throw out the value stack except for the parameters you explicitly pass in. What you probably want is chain, which snowballs the value stack.

See here for a list of result types, the link to Chain has some examples: http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/result-types.html

You can then just use the basic result tag and probably will not need a body.

See nmc's comment.  This is what I do too, it isn't a good idea to use chain or redirectAction... creates spaghetti actions.